# Python Selenium get element content

Tags: python, selenium

If I do

```
match = driver.find_element_by_class_name("match")
print(match.text)
```

I only get the text in the element.

```
<class id="match">
    This is a text. This is displayed with .text
    <p align="center"><a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></p>
    The above is not displayed with .text
</class>
```

What to do when I also want the html in the element, not only the text?

Comment: `match` variable is the element.

Comment: Try `match.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get HTML code inside an element but *not including* the code of the element you should use this:

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML');
```

If you want to get HTML code inside an element *including* the code of the element then you should use this:

```
element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```